# Solving recurrence

Tags: asymptotics

How to solve the recursion:

$
T(n) = 
\begin{cases}
T(n/2) + O(1),  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
T(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + O(1), & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$

I think $T(n)$ is $O(\log n)$. Can somebody show a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function appears in Sung-Hyuk Cha, [On Parity based Divide and Conquer Recursive
Functions](http://csis.pace.edu/~scha/IS/FOGKN.pdf).

Let us consider the following version:
$$
T(n) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } n = 0,1, \\
2 & \text{if } n = 2, \\
T(n/2) + 1 & \text{if } n \geq 4 \text{ is even}, \\
T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + T(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + 1 & \text{if } n \geq 3 \text{ is odd}.
\end{cases}
$$
You can calculate that
$$
T\left(\frac{7 \cdot 2^n - (-1)^n}{3}\right) = 2F_{n+4} - 2F_{n+1} - 2.
$$
For example, $T(2) = 2$, $T(5) = 6$, $T(9) = 10$ (these correspond to $n=0,1,2$).

This gives an infinite sequence of $n$'s such that
$$
T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_2 \phi}),
$$
where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. Empirically, this sequence maximizes the exponent.

The limiting exponent is roughly $0.694241913630617$.

See the related sequences [A215673](https://oeis.org/A215673) and [A215675](https://oeis.org/A215675), which correspond to slightly different initial conditions.

The sequence of worst-case inputs is [A062092](http://oeis.org/A062092), and that of worst-case outputs is [A001595](http://oeis.org/A001595).

---

Let us prove the claimed formula. Let $a_n = [7 \cdot 2^n - (-1)^n]/3$. Then $a_0 = 2$, and $a_n = 2a_{n-1} - (-1)^n$ for $n > 0$. If $n > 0$ is even then
$$
\begin{align*}
T(a_n) &= 1 + T(a_{n-1}) + T(a_{n-1} - 1) \\ &=
1 + T(a_{n-1}) + T(2a_{n-2}) \\ &=
2 + T(a_{n-1}) + T(a_{n-2}).
\end{align*}
$$
Similarly, if $n>1$ is odd then
$$
\begin{align*}
T(a_n) &= 1 + T(a_{n-1}) + T(a_{n-1}+1) \\ &=
1 + T(a_{n-1}) + T(2a_{n-2}) \\ &=
2 + T(a_{n-1}) + T(a_{n-2}).
\end{align*}
$$
Denoting $b_n = T(a_n)/2$, we get $b_0 = 1$, $b_1 = 3$, and $b_n = b_{n-1} + b_{n-2} + 1$ for $n \geq 2$. The sequence $b'_n = b_n + 1$ satisfies the recurrence $b'_n = b'_{n-1} + b'_{n-2}$, from which it is easy to find an explicit formula.

---

In the other direction, let us notice that when $n$ is odd, exactly one of $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor,\lceil n/2 \rceil$ is odd, and the other is even. This shows that for all $n$, we have
$$
T(n) \leq T(n/2 + O(1)) + T(n/4 + O(1)) + O(1).
$$
According to the [Akra–Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), the solution to this recurrence is $T(n) = O(n^p)$, where $p$ is the solution to
$$
\frac{1}{2^p} + \frac{1}{4^p} = 1.
$$
(To deduce that from the theorem requires a bit of work; briefly, you compare $T$ to another recurrence $T'$ which is defined like $T$ on odd inputs but in a different way for even inputs; $T'$ satisfies the recurrence above exactly, and induction shows that $T \leq T'$.)

Let $x = 2^p$. Then $1/x + 1/x^2 = 1$, and so $x^2 = x + 1$. This is the familiar Fibonacci recurrence, with solutions $x = (1 \pm \sqrt{5})/2$. Only one of them is positive, and we conclude that $p = \log_2 \phi$. Therefore
$$
T(n) = O(n^{\log_2 \phi}).
$$
As we have seen above, the exponent is tight for infinitely many $n$. Since these $n$ are dense enough, we can conclude that
$$
\max (T(0),\ldots,T(n)) = \Theta(n^{\log_2 \phi}).
$$

Comment: The upper bound can also be found in Sung-Hyuk Cha's paper, using a slightly different method.